# Non persistent checking on Flutter Login

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, authentication, asynchronous

In my Flutter App I'm using Firebase Auth to authenticate the users. I have `login_service` with `Provider` and in the `main.dart` I check the state of the login.

My flow is:

1. Check if the user is logged with `trackUserState()`
2. If the user is logged I check the database: if the user exist I go to the HomeScreen, if not to the registration screen

My problem is that where I'm checking if the user is logged or not (on the `main.dart`, inside the routes object) generates a problem: the function is being executed all the time, nonstop.

How can I refactor this to only execute the function on init and after that notify only the changes (logout, a logged but non registered user being registered...) with `notifyListeners()`?

This are the codes of both files, `main.dart` and `login_service.dart`:

`main.dart`

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginState>(
      create: (context) => LoginState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routes: {
          // ignore: missing_return
          '/': (BuildContext context) {

            var state = Provider.of<LoginState>(context);
            state.trackUserState();


            if(state.userExist() == false) {
              return RegisterScreen();
            }
            if(state.isLoggedIn() == true) {
              return HomeScreen();
            }
            if (state.isLoggedIn() == false) {
              return LoginScreen();
            }


          },
          ...here the other routes
        },
        theme: brightTheme,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`login_service.dart`

```
class LoginState with ChangeNotifier {

//  Instances
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


//  Variables
  User _user;
  bool _userExist;
  bool _loading = false;
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  String _userEmail;

//  Functions to track
  bool isLoggedIn() => _isLoggedIn;
  bool isLoading() => _loading;
  bool userExist() => _userExist;
  User currentUser() => _user;
  String getUserEmail() => _userEmail;



//  Registration Flow
  void goAheadAfterRegistration() async {
    if (_user != null) {
      var userExist = await _firestore.collection('users').where('email', isEqualTo: _user.email).get();
      if (userExist.docs.length == 1) {

      } else {
        print('Este user aun no se ha registrado');
        _userExist = false;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      _loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void checkUserOnDatabase() async {

    var userExistOnDatabase = await _firestore.collection('users').where('email', isEqualTo: _user.email).get();

    if (userExistOnDatabase.docs.length == 1) {
        _isLoggedIn = true;
        _userExist = true;
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        _userExist = false;
        notifyListeners();
    }
      notifyListeners();
    }


//  LogOut the user
  void logout() async {
    _googleSignIn.signOut();
    _auth.signOut();
    _loading = false;
    _isLoggedIn = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }


//  Tracking the user state

  void trackUserState() {
    _auth.authStateChanges()
        .listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        _isLoggedIn = false;
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        _user = user;
        checkUserOnDatabase();
        notifyListeners();
      }
    });
  }

  //  Third party login providers
  void googleLogin() async {
    _loading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _user = await _handleSignIn();
    checkUserOnDatabase();
  }

  Future<User> _handleSignIn() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final User user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    return user;
  }

  // TODO on login true circular progress indicator while we check if the user exist to prevent new logins

}
```

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  *handle all that 1 trigger stuff here*
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks! It worked. I have a little error during a microsecond but I think it will work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you share that stack trace ill try and debug it